# resizing Div via a python callback in Bokeh

Tags: bokeh

I have a plot where I would like to dynamically populate a div on user tap of data points in the first plot and automatically move the second plot downwards. I have tried setting the sizing_mode on the layout but The plots do not render. This may be an interaction with the tab widget. So far the python callback is correctly trigger on tap but the Div's height remains the same and text gets cut off.

The call back is as follows,

```
def update_plot_points_select(attr, old, new):        
    #function to change Divs if points are selected
    #tap can either be a tap or untap, 1 or more points
    #Show chosen word in text box
    if len(new['1d']['indices']) > 0:
        #update search text input field
        text_input_word_search_in_documents.value = source.data['term'][new['1d']['indices'][0]]
        #update Div's
        text_display_category_div.update(text=source.data['term'][new['1d']['indices'][0]]+'<br/>'+'line')
        text_display_category_div.update(height=600)
        text_display_not_category_div.update(text=source.data['term'][new['1d']['indices'][0]]+'<br/>'+'line')
        text_display_not_category_div.update(height=600)
        category_scatter_graph_layout.children[0].children[1].children[1].children[0].height = 600
        category_scatter_graph_layout.children[0].children[1].children[1].children[1].height = 600
    else:
        text_input_word_search_in_documents.value = ''
        text_display_category_div.update(text='')
        text_display_category_div.update(height=0)
        text_display_not_category_div.update(text='')
        text_display_not_category_div.update(height=0)      
        category_scatter_graph_layout.children[0].children[1].children[1].children[0].height = 0
        category_scatter_graph_layout.children[0].children[1].children[1].children[1].height = 0
```

As you can see I am trying to set both the Div and parent widgetbox's height back forth from 0 to 600 but the plot does not update. Perhaps I can solve this problem in the html of the div.text. Any ideas would be helpful.

The cut off text of the Div is shown below.

[image: Cutoff text of Div]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out one possible solution. Setting the layout with a non fixed sizing mode messed up the plots but wrapping the individual Divs inside a widgetbox inside my layout with a sizing_mode of scale_height achieved the solution I needed.

```
widgetbox([text_display_category_div,text_display_not_category_div],sizing_mode = 'scale_height')
```